# My AddEventListener function is not working in any browser. How can this be solved?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my JS code:

```js
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
const CATEGORIES_URL = `${BASE_URL}/categories`;
const ITEMS_URL = `${BASE_URL}/items`;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  getCategories();
  createNewCategory();
});

const main = () => {
  return document.querySelector("main");
};

//loads all the categories
const getCategories = () => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => renderCategories(data));
};

const renderCategories = (categoriesData) => {
  categoriesData.forEach((category) => renderCategoriesCard(category));
};

const renderCategoriesCard = (categories) => {
  let categoriesCard = document.createElement("div");
  categoriesCard.className = "card";
  categoriesCard.dataset.id = categories.id;
  categoriesCard.innerHTML = `
    <p>${categories.name}</p>
    <button data-category-id=${categories.id}>Add Item</button>
  `;
  categoriesCard.lastElementChild.addEventListener("click", displayItemForm);
  main().appendChild(categoriesCard);
  let itemsList = document.createElement("ul");
  itemsList.setAttribute("class", "items-list");
  itemsList.dataset.id = categories.id;
  categoriesCard.appendChild(itemsList);

  categories.items.forEach((item) => renderItems(item, itemsList));
};

const createNewCategory = () => {
  let form = document.querySelector("a");
  form.addEventListener("click", displayCategoryForm);
};

const displayCategoryForm = () => {
  let categoryForm = document.getElementById("category-form");
  let html = `
  <form>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  `;

  categoryForm.innerHTML = html;
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", createCategory);
};

const createCategory = () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Form clicked");

const category = {
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
};

//createNewCategory();



  //fetch POST
  fetch(CATEGORIES_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(category),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      renderCategoriesCard(data);
      clearCategoryForm();
    });
};

const renderItems = (item, list) => {
  let itemCard = document.createElement("li");
  itemCard.id = `item-${item.id}`;
  itemCard.innerText = `Title: ${item.title}`;
  let releaseBtn = document.createElement("button");
  releaseBtn.className = "delete";
  releaseBtn.dataset.itemId = item.id;
  releaseBtn.innerText = "Delete";
  releaseBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
  ItemCard.appendChild(releaseBtn);
  if (!list) {
    list = event.target.parentElement.lastElementChild;
  }
  list.appendChild(itemCard);
};

const clearForm = () => {
  let item = document.getElementById("item-form");
  item.innerHTML = "";
};
const clearCategoryForm = () => {
  let category = document.getElementById("category-form");
  category.innerHTML = "";
};

const deleteItem = () => {
  fetch(ITEMS_URL + `/${event.target.dataset.ItemId}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
  }).then(removeItem(event.target.dataset.itemId));
};

const removeItem = (id) => {
  let cardToRemove = document.getElementById(`item-${id}`);
  cardToRemove.parentElement.removeChild(cardToRemove);
};

const displayItemForm = () => {
  let itemForm = document.getElementById("item-form");
  let html = `
  <form data-category-id="${event.target.dataset.categoryId}">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title">
    <label>Item Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" id="body">
    <input type="submit" value"Submit">
  </form>
  `;

  itemForm.innerHTML = html;
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", createItem);
};

const createItem = () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("adding items...");
  let categoryCardId = event.target.dataset.categoryId;
  console.log(categoryCardId);
  const item = {
    title: document.getElementById("title").value,
    quantity: document.getElementById("quantity").value,
    category_id: categoryCardId,
  };
  //createItem(); 

  console.log(item);

  fetch(ITEMS_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let item = new Item(data);
      item.renderItem();
      clearForm();
    });
};
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Groceries</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src= "src/index.js"></script>
        <script src= "src/item.js"></script>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Red+Rose:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Groceries</h1>

        <a id="categoryForm" href="#">Add New Category</a>
        <div id="category-form"></div>
        <main id="category-container">
            <div id="item-form"></div> 
        </main>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I've tried so many things and this just doesnt seem to work. I cannot click the link, nothing happens in any browser.

Nothing seems to work passed the "Create new Category" part. I'm not sure why Im not able to add a new item. When I hit "submit" on adding an item, the program pauses at "adding item..." and then gives an error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `createNewCategory ` seems to be never invoked in your code. Where is it invoked? Also, `createCategory` is undefined.

Comment: Heres my code: 

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  getCategories();
  createNewCategory();
  searchForCategories();
});

Comment: @maryjane kindly check the answer, i hope that will give you a better understanding, I have mentioned what you have missed too. Your code was running just some things missed

Comment: created a snippet out of your question, there are no issues :)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thanks so much for the answers! I actually have invoked createNewCategory at the top of my page like this : 

window.addEventListener("load", () => { getCategories(); createNewCategory(); searchForCategories(); });

Comment: @Greedo Oh wow thank you! For some reason it still doesnt work in my project.

Comment: @maryjane Happy to help maryjane, no issues even though you are a new contributor to stackoverflow, you have posted the question with much more clarity. Hope the answer helped kindly accept so it will be helpful for the future reference.

Comment: I don't consider "I've tried so many things and this just doesnt seem to work" particularly clear.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I'm actually having an issue again, would you be kind enough to check out my newly edited question? Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @briosheje  I've posted an edit to my question where you can see how I've invoked the method. However, I am still having issues here.

Comment: @maryjane sorry the delayed reply, was busy in some work. can you let me know what is missing in the updated question, on submit whatever you have entered should list, is that what you are looking 

Answer (score 1):

Two things in your code

1. Need to invoke the createNewCategory
2. **addEventListener("submit", createCategory)** Either you missed this function in the question, for now added a simple function

Check the below snippet

```js
const createNewCategory = () => {
  let form = document.querySelector("a");
  form.addEventListener("click", displayCategoryForm);
};

const displayCategoryForm = () => {
  let categoryForm = document.getElementById("category-form");
  let html = `
  <form>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  `;

  categoryForm.innerHTML = html;
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", createCategory);
};

createNewCategory()

const createCategory = () => alert('i am createCategroy function')
```

```html
<a id="categoryForm" href="#">Add New Category</a>
<div id="category-form"></div>
```